# Where is the error? i want to add comment by user and it give me error

Tags: php, laravel

***here my controller ***

```
    public function create(Request $request){



    return $addComment=Comment::create([
        'description'=>$request->comment,
        'commentable_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
        'commentable_type'=>'App\User'
    ]);
```

***//here my form***

```
 <form method="post"   action="{{route('comments')}}">
                                @csrf
                            <label for="comment">Şərh yaz</label><br>&nbsp;

                            <textarea id="comment " name="comment" rows="3" cols="50">

                            </textarea>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Şərh yaz</button>
                            </form>
```

***///how can i solve this error?***  i built polymorphic relationship in models.

Comment: Before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: i use this in Comment model.  protected $fillable=['description, commentable_id, commentable_type'];

Comment: Can you please show, error you getting?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'description' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-08-20 10:14:18, 2020-08-20 10:14:18))

Answer (score 1):

You have to define this :

```
$fillable=['description, commentable_id, commentable_type'];
```

To this:

```
$fillable=['description', 'commentable_id', 'commentable_type'];
```

Comment: i dont understand you. Both of codes is the same. i use $fillable=['description, commentable_id, commentable_type']; in my model

Comment: No, That are not same you are using `' . . .'` on all column names. Please look above carefully to find difference.

Comment: It work thank you.  so how i get specific post comments? Because i dont use post_id in my Comments table

Comment: Please check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), Else you can ask another question and post all details regarding to get post comments.

Comment: Sorry, Not possible. You can ask questions.

Comment: okay this is last question. should i  create post_id and user_id in my comment tables ? or should i just create commentable_id and commentable_type? So is this relationship must be polymorphic or just hasMany relation?

Comment: In `commentable_id` you have to insert post/user id  and in `commentable_type` you have to use `App\Post` for post comment corresponding to post model  and `App\User` for user comment corresponding to user model.

Comment: i know. but how Comment table understand which post commented?

Comment: Please create separate question.